# Gradle task does not accept Java user input

Tags: java, gradle

I utilised springboot to create a gradle project `MortgageCalculator`. After building the project with `./gradlew build` I have the following directory tree:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       ├── main
│   │       │   └── com
│   │       │       └── tian
│   │       │           └── MortgageCalculator
│   │       │               ├── DemoApplication.class
│   │       │               └── Main.class
│   │       └── test
│   │           └── com
│   │               └── tian
│   │                   └── MortgageCalculator
│   │                       └── DemoApplicationTests.class
|   ...
| 
├── build.gradle
|
|
...
|
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── tian
    │   │           └── MortgageCalculator
    │   │               ├── DemoApplication.java
    │   │               └── Main.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.properties
   ...
```

---

The source code for `Main.java` is

```java
package com.tian.MortgageCalculator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        // initialising tools
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        byte a = scanner.nextByte();
    }
}
```

---

I then define a task within `build.gradle`

```
task Main(type: JavaExec) {
        main = 'com.tian.MortgageCalculator.Main'
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

---

But when I run `./gradlew Main`. I get the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:2002)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Scanner.java:1956)
  at com.tian.MortgageCalculator.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

I think the problem is that running a task this way does not allow for user input into the system in, but how should I define my task to allow it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re probably looking for [the `standardInput` property](https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/JavaExec.html#setStandardInput-java.io.InputStream-) of the `JavaExec` task type. Using the following task definition, the setup worked for me (tested with Gradle 6.8.2):

```
task Main(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.tian.MortgageCalculator.Main'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
}
```